Mod rewrite NC,L,QSA for SEO?
I just got mod_rewrite working. In my .htaccess file I put in the code:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

it does exactly what I want, but I couldn't figure out what the NC,L,QSA mean. Are those the options I want for SEO? Basically I want everything to go to one index.php and that page to serve up all the requests. I haven't done a real project for years, just want to make sure I'm doing everything right.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
